# Google Maps API - Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-maps

Is it necessary to remove Event listeners in when using google maps javascript api? 
"assume that code is working fine"

In other words do even listeners hinder website performance in such a way that one should ALWAYS remove/minimized unused listeners.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about `GEvent`'s from the Google Maps API. Personally, I haven't had any difficulties with them.

Nor have I had any problems with adding say jQuery `.mouseup()` on the map canvas to trigger map events, although I recommend using `GEvent`'s for triggering and handling map-related stuff.

Edit: It'd be interesting with some profiling on having a simple map canvas, and see if other actions and performance is affected by removing GEvents.